# Is my proof that $H^1(X,F) = 0$ for the skyscraper sheaf correct?

Tags: group-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be compact connected. Let $F$ be the skyscraper sheaf over $p$ for a group $G$. Let $H^1(X,F)$ be the first Cech cohomology of the sheaf. We want to show $\ker(d_1) = im(d_0)$ is trivial. It suffices to show $d_0(C_0) = 0$ Choose some cover of $X$, if $p \in U_{i}$, then for $g \in F(U_i)$ we have $g|_{U_i \cap U_j} - g|_{U_i \cap U_j} = 0$.

This seems too easy, am I missing something?

Comment: Even better: can you show that you can get a cover such that only one element of the cover contains $p$? Then you get that there are no 1-Cech cocycles.

Comment: Taking a refinement does the trick?

Comment: Yeah should be good.